# Can't get output from GP5 and GP3 in PIC12F629

Tags: microcontroller, pic, mplabx

I can't get output from GP5 and GP3 from a PIC12F629 I have. My code is the following:

```
#include <xc.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000
#pragma config WDTE=OFF , BOREN=OFF , PWRTE=ON , MCLRE=OFF , FOSC=INTRCIO

void main(){
TRISIO = 0;
GPIO = 0;
    while(1){
        GPIO = 1b11111;
    }

}
```

When I connected the resistor and LED to other pins, every LED lights up, except those connected to pin 2 and 4. I verified both the LED and resistor and they are working ok. The MCU is brand new. I even tested this setup with another, used IC before.

**What did I do wrong?**

Can some one explain what `1b` or `0b` in GPIO value mean? I guess `b` could be binary.

Note: My IDE is MPLAB X, XC8.

Comment: Normally it would be `0b` for binary but not all compilers support that (not sure about the one included with MPLAB) but try `0xFF` instead and see what happens.

Comment: thank's, it lite GP5 but GP3 is off.

Comment: GP5 and GP3 are different to pin 5 and pin 3, perhaps edit your question to clarify which one you mean.

Comment: My mistake, i corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the table on page 6 of the [PIC12F629 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/41190c.pdf), it lists GP3 as:

> Input port w/ interrupt-on-change

Then again on page 23:

> Figure 3-3 shows the diagram for this pin. The GP3 pin is configurable
>   to function as one of the following:
>
> • a general purpose input
>
> • as Master Clear Reset

GP3 can only be used as an input on this device.

As noted in the comments the `1b` prefix is unusual, modern Microchip compilers in the XC range all support the standard `0b` as a prefix which indicates a binary radix number.

In your original code you listed `1b11111` as the value for the port.  If we read from right to left this would set GP0, GP1, GP2, GP3 and GP4 to the value 1 (but note that GP3 isn't an output, as above).  You don't have enough digits to set GP5 to 1.

If you set your output port to `0b111111` you are now setting GP0 to GP5 (again reading right to left).

Comment: I just tested this in a recent XC8, it allows you to specify numbers as `7b101010`.  Very unusual that this doesn't generate a warning.  Don't do this though - `0b101010` is the correct notation.

Comment: For pin2 or GP5 i used GPIO = 0b100000; and it works.